# Multipart Rest controller to consumes xml and binary file data with a boundary value

Tags: multipartform-data, multipart, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to consume a multipart request which consumes xml and file content(binary base64) data.

Sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/multimixed", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes={"multipart/mixed"})
    public @ResponseBody String createActivityTemplateMixed(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
    {   
System.out.println(request.getParts());
        return "test";
    }
```

Testing from post man with the below data

Sample header:

> content-type=multipart/mixed;boundary ="dhfsdjkfhsdklfjksdhfsdl"

Sample request:

`--dhfsdjkfhsdklfjksdhfsdl
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.txt"
  Content-Type: application/xml
  <somecontent>content</somecontent>
  --dhfsdjkfhsdklfjksdhfsdl
  Content-Type: audio/wav
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=”audio123.wav”
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
  [base 64 data jhlsjh;fkldajsdjaskldjls;k] 
  --dhfsdjkfhsdklfjksdhfsdl--`

getparts() on the request is returning null and I am expecting the data sent in the request so that I can iterate the headers and body to process it further.
Please suggest me a way to handle a multipart request from which I can get individual request.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Which version of Spring jar are you using, because getParts() is not a method in spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE, instead I am using request.getMultiFileMap() method to get the content of the request.